# Print only first and last matching patterns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am new to scripting and am learning as I go, I appreciate all and any help you can provide.  I have a file with the following data:

```
0252    Fri 03 Jul 2015      84082679  
0252    Fri 10 Jul 2015      81473945  
0252    Fri 17 Jul 2015      87405062  
0252    Fri 24 Jul 2015      89400396  
0253    Fri 03 Jul 2015      29038894  
0253    Fri 10 Jul 2015      29392107  
0253    Fri 17 Jul 2015      31271055  
0253    Fri 24 Jul 2015      31367348  
071    Fri 03 Jul 2015      18594024  
071    Fri 10 Jul 2015      18568430  
071    Fri 17 Jul 2015      18648903  
071    Fri 24 Jul 2015      18887643  
072    Fri 03 Jul 2015      20141235  
072    Fri 10 Jul 2015      19563727  
072    Fri 17 Jul 2015      19573266
```

My desired output would look like:

```
0252    Fri 03 Jul 2015      84082679  
0252    Fri 24 Jul 2015      89400396  
0253    Fri 03 Jul 2015      29038894  
0253    Fri 24 Jul 2015      31367348  
071    Fri 03 Jul 2015      18594024  
071    Fri 24 Jul 2015      18887643  
072    Fri 03 Jul 2015      20141235  
072    Fri 17 Jul 2015      19573266
```

The first column in the input data defines the "groups". From each group I want to print exactly two lines: the first line and the last line.

I would like to use awk to get my desired result, as i am trying to sort this information as final output.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between your input and output? Am I missing something obvious? I.e. What are you trying to get your code to do?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, I've just edited the question to add a sentence that might clear it up. *"The first column in the input data defines the "groups". From each group I want to print exactly two lines: the first line and the last line."*

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane '
            if ($F[0] eq $id) {
                $keep = $_
            } else {
                $id = $F[0];
                print $keep if defined $keep;
                print
            }
            }{ print $keep
            ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the `@F` array
- `-l` adds newline to `print`
- `$id` is used to keep the value from the first column
- `$keep` remembers the last line. When the `$id` changes, `$keep` and the current line are printed.
- after the Eskimo greeting operator `}{`, the last line is printed once the whole file has been processed.

Comment: So, to clarify the question: column 1 "groups" the data. From each group we print exactly two lines. Specifically, the first line and the last line. *Note however*, that in the sample data, each group is internally ordered by date - it is your understanding that this ordering is an irrelevance. Is this correct? Perhaps you could edit your answer to clarify which question you're answering?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: It prints the first and last line for each ID in column one. The only assumption it makes is that each "block" must be continuous. The question doesn't mention dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v h=99 'h>$3{if (last) print last;print;} {h=$3;last=$0;} END{print last}' file
0252    Fri 03 Jul 2015      84082679  
0252    Fri 24 Jul 2015      89400396  
0253    Fri 03 Jul 2015      29038894  
0253    Fri 24 Jul 2015      31367348  
071    Fri 03 Jul 2015      18594024  
071    Fri 24 Jul 2015      18887643  
072    Fri 03 Jul 2015      20141235  
072    Fri 17 Jul 2015      19573266
```

#### How it works

The script uses two variables: `h` and `last`.  `h` is the value of the third field on the previous line and `last` is the text of the last line.  Any decrease in `h` triggers printing.

- `-v h=99`

  Set initial value of `h` to a large number.
- `h>$3{if (last) print last;print;}`

  If `h` is larger than field 3, then print both the previous line (if there is one) and the current line.
- `h=$3;last=$0;`

  Update `h` and `last`.
- `END{print last}`

  Print the last line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1p;N;/^(\S+\s+).*\n\1/D;2s/.*\n//' file
```

Always print the first line. Append the next line to the current line and compare the first field of the first with the first field of the second. It they are the same delete the first and repeat. Otherwise, print both lines but only the second if on line 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != p1 { print p0 $0 }
{ p1 = $1; p0 = $0 ORS }
END { printf "%s", p0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
0252    Fri 03 Jul 2015      84082679
0252    Fri 24 Jul 2015      89400396
0253    Fri 03 Jul 2015      29038894
0253    Fri 24 Jul 2015      31367348
071    Fri 03 Jul 2015      18594024
071    Fri 24 Jul 2015      18887643
072    Fri 03 Jul 2015      20141235
072    Fri 17 Jul 2015      19573266
```